# from Settings to App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking for a way in iOS8 to start an App from the Settingmenu. 
So if I jumped into the settings from the app, after configuration I want jump back to the app.
Is it possible?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to go back to your app programmatically from Settings app. User has to manually open the app that is in background.